# C# if statements not working in console game (I'm a beginner so it may be completely wrong)

Tags: c#

The `if` statements are supposed to print whether or not I have won, lost or drawn in the game of rock, paper, scissors. This is not happening though.

Expected Result:
Please input either rock, paper or scissors

The computer has chosen:
Paper

You have Won!!

Actual Result:
Please input either rock, paper or scissors

The computer has chosen:
Paper

I don't have the best understanding of programming in general otherwise I probably would be able to figure this out on my own.

The reason I have started with C# is because I am learning that at school at the moment so I thought learning at home as well would give me a better chance at understanding it quickly.

This is my code, is there anything wrong? (Please make it as simple as possible since I have only really started C# a couple of days ago)

```
string appName = "Rock, Paper, Scissors";
string appVersion = "1.0.0";
string author = "Rhys Keown";

Console.WriteLine("{0}, Version {1}, Made By {2}", appName, appVersion, author);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to begin the game!");
Console.ReadKey();

// Ask for the user to input either Rock, Paper, Scissors
Console.WriteLine("Please input either Rock, Paper or Scissors");
string userOpt = Console.ReadLine();

// Random option completed by the computer.
string[] rpsOpt = new string[] { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
Console.WriteLine("The computer has chosen:");
Console.WriteLine(rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)]);

string finalOpt = Console.ReadLine();

// If the selection of the user beats the computer then You Win! 
// is printed and you are asked if you want to have another game.
string a = userOpt;
string b = finalOpt;

if (b == "Rock" && a == "Rock")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have drawn"); 
}

if (b == "Paper" && a == "Paper")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have drawn"); 
}

if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Scissors") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have drawn");   
}

if (b == "Rock" && a == "Scissors") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have lost"); 
}

if (b == "Rock" && a == "Paper") 
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have won!!"); 
}

if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Rock")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have won!!"); 
}

if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Paper")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have lost");     
}

if (b == "Paper" && a == "Scissors")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have won!!");
}

if (b == "Paper" && a == "Rock")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have lost");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: "This is not happenning though" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53637041/edit) to let us know what you entered, what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it?

Comment: `b` will only be Rock, Paper or Scissors if the user enters it **again** at the second prompt. There are *two* things you need to learn first when programming, they are programming and debugging. Put a breakpoint somewhere before your `if` statements and step through your code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies within this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)]);
```

You're writing computers choice on the console output, but you're not actually storing that choice anywhere.

```
string finalOpt = Console.ReadLine();
```

The line above then waits for another user input and you're probably just pressing `Enter` key once again, which results in an empty string being stored in `finalOpt` variable.

After that, you're comparing user's first choice, with an empty string from the `finalOpt` variable and none of your `if` conditions handle that case. That's why you're not seeing any output.

In order to fix that, you need to first store the random choice into variable and then print it out to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine("The Computer has chosen:");
string finalOpt = rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)];
Console.WriteLine(finalOpt);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the following code lines

```
Console.WriteLine(rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)]);
string finalOpt = Console.ReadLine();
```

You print out the random Computer selection. After you print out the selection you are waiting for an input. So the string `finalOpt` contains the user input not the random selection.

You have to put the random selection into the `finalOpt` string and print out this string.

```
string finalOpt = rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)];
Console.WriteLine(finalOpt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are making code problem at these lines:

[image]

I Corrected your Code.
**Try it:**

```
using System;

namespace SimpleGame
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate int SquareDelegate(int number);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appName = "Rock, Paper, Scissors";
            string appVersion = "1.0.0";
            string author = "Rhys Keown";

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, Version {1}, Made By {2}", appName, appVersion, author);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to begin the game!");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Ask for the user to input either Rock, Paper, Scissors
            Console.WriteLine("Please input either Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            string userOpt = Console.ReadLine();

            // Random option completed by the computer.
            string[] rpsOpt = new string[] { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
            Console.WriteLine("The computer has chosen:");


            // Computer Chosen value - Stored to 'b'
            string b = rpsOpt[new Random().Next(0, rpsOpt.Length)];


            //string finalOpt = Console.ReadLine();

            // If the selection of the user beats the computer then You Win! 
            // is printed and you are asked if you want to have another game.
            string a = userOpt;

            if (b == "Rock" && a == "Rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have drawn");
            }

            else if (b == "Paper" && a == "Paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have drawn");
            }

            else if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have drawn");
            }

            else if (b == "Rock" && a == "Scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have lost");
            }

            else if (b == "Rock" && a == "Paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have won!!");
            }

            else if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have won!!");
            }

            else if (b == "Scissors" && a == "Paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have lost");
            }

            else if (b == "Paper" && a == "Scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have won!!");
            }

            else if (b == "Paper" && a == "Rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have lost");
            }
            else (b == "Paper" && a == "Rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something Wrong When Computing results..");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: How is this answer better than the one posted well before yours and that actually explains what the problem is instead of just correcting the code?

Comment: @Crowcoder - I just saw the Question and Copy/Paste Code from Question to visual studio and findout what the problem Is...and then solve the problem and post the answer....